# Keras merge VS concatenate, can't update my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras functional model for a CNN. I'm trying to implement a triplet-loss function. I found some posts about who to do that using "merge", which is now deprecated, but I'm not able to use "concatenate" as I was using merge.

The original code looks like this:

```
def triplet_loss(x):
    anchor, positive, negative = x
    pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), 1)
    neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), 1)

    basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), 0.05)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0), 0)
    return loss



def build_model(img_x, img_y):
    input_shape = Input(shape=(img_x, img_y, 3))
    c0 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu') (input_shape)
    m0 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)) (c0)
    f = Flatten()(m0)
    d1 = Dense(4024, activation='relu')(f)
    d2 = Dense(512, activation='sigmoid')(d1)

    anchor = Input(shape=(128, 254, 3))
    positive = Input(shape=(128, 254, 3))
    negative = Input(shape=(128, 254, 3))

    reid_model = Model(inputs=[input_shape], outputs=[d2])

    anchor_embed = reid_model(anchor)
    positive_embed = reid_model(positive)
    negative_embed = reid_model(negative)

    loss = merge([anchor_embed, positive_embed, negative_embed],
             mode=triplet_loss, output_shape=(1,))

    model = Model(inputs=[anchor, positive, negative], outputs=loss)
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mean_absolute_error')
    return model
```

I was using `loss = merge([anchor_embed, positive_embed, negative_embed], mode=triplet_loss, output_shape=(1,))` as a way to transform the output of the function `triplet_loss` into a keras layer output (as suggested in https://codepad.co/snippet/F1uVDD5N). The function `concatenate` doesn't have a parameter "mode". HIs there any way to adapt my code to get the result of the loss function as a Keras layer output?

Comment: One direct way to tweak your code is to do this:

merged_output = concatenate([anchor_embed, positive_embed, negative_embed])

model = Model(inputs=[anchor, positive, negative], outputs=merged_output)

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=triplet_loss, metrics=[triplet_loss])


By doing this way, if you want to checkpoint and restore you Keras model, you might have to do it like this for example:
model = load_model('/path/to/model', custom_objects={'triplet_loss': triplet_loss})

Let me know if this works!

Comment: Hey @kvish, I tried that, the only problem is that the "concatenate" function returns a `Tensor("concatenate_1/concat:0", shape=(?, 1536), dtype=float32)` object, so, when the `triplet_loss` function is called I have an error relative to the number of inputs. Do you know how to "deconcatenate" the layer to be able to compute the loss. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using [tf.split](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) to get the respective tensors?

Comment: @kvish the problem with this solution is that I still need my output to be:
``model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['accuracy'])``
If I change to 
``model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=triplet_loss, metrics=[triplet_loss])``
How can I set the loss as the "mean_absolute_error"?

Comment: If you are using triplet loss, then that is your actual loss function that you are defining, and it is what needs to be minimized to evaluate your problem. Refer to this [blog post](https://omoindrot.github.io/triplet-loss) for more details regarding the triplet loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to compute the value of the `triplet_loss` function keeping the original architecture of my code by adding a lambda layer.

```
def triplet_loss(x):
    anchor, positive, negative = x
    pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), 1)
    neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), 1)

    basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), 0.05)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0), 0)
    return loss

def build_model(img_x, img_y):
    input_shape = Input(shape=(img_x, img_y, 3))
    c0 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu') 
(input_shape)
    m0 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)) (c0)
    f = Flatten()(m0)
    d1 = Dense(4024, activation='relu')(f)
    d2 = Dense(512, activation='sigmoid')(d1)

    anchor = Input(shape=(128, 254, 3))
    positive = Input(shape=(128, 254, 3))
    negative = Input(shape=(128, 254, 3))

    reid_model = Model(inputs=[input_shape], outputs=[d2])

    anchor_embed = reid_model(anchor)
    positive_embed = reid_model(positive)
    negative_embed = reid_model(negative)

    merged_output = concatenate([anchor_embed, positive_embed, 
negative_embed])
    loss = Lambda(triplet_loss, (1,))(merged_output)

    model = Model(inputs=[anchor, positive, negative], outputs=loss)
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse',
                  metrics=["mae"])
    return model
```